# How to get past Cloudflare's javascript challenge in nhentai when using curl?

Tags: bash, shell, web-scraping, curl, cookies

The server throws a 403 error when I use curl to request it.

Basically TL;DR: I have an ID, let's say `177013`, and I want to get the cover image of the gallery.

What I learnt is that the image server, which is in the format of `https://t[[:digit:]]\.nhentai\.net/galleries/[[:digit:]]*/cover\.[[:lower:]]`, does not have a javascript barrier and you can curl or even wget the URL to download the cover image, like `t7.nhentai.net/gallery/2523415/cover.jpg`, without the need of anything else.

It's just the `nhentai.net/g/[[ID]]` page that has this Cloudflare challenge.

But the problem is, the `[[:digit:]]` is different from the ID, so there's no way of getting that image server's digit just from the ID.

So I tried searching for solutions, and found the `hentai-chan/hentai` package which is written in python. Unfortunately, I am developing a bash script and am trying to minimize the dependencies of my package, which are currently `('neofetch' 'w3m' 'chafa' 'jq' 'curl' 'bash' 'sed' 'grep')`, and only want to use curl without python.

When I continue researching, I found most projects use `wholesomelist.com`'s API to get the cover image, which doesn't quite work for *some* IDs (like 177013).

Then I found `gallery-dl` which manages to successfully download images straight from the website using extractors, but still don't understand how it does even after reading its source code. I think it uses cookies or act like a browser. But I don't want to use the entire `gallery-dl` package as it is quite heavily large in size, and I don't know if I can just extract the cover url as it downloads just the pages (`/gallery/1.jpg, 2.jpg, etc.`).

So I tried putting cookies into curl by using this method that ChatGPT has given me:

```bash
Click on the first request (200 GET nhentai.net /), and copy the value of the cookie header (which is in the Request Headers section at the bottom).

1. Open nhentai.net in your browser
2. Open the developer tools (F12)
3. Go to the network tab
4. Reload the page
5. Click on the first request (Usually 200 GET nhentai.net /)
6. Scroll down to the request headers
7. Copy the Cookie value
```

Then doing

```bash
curl -s -H "Cookie: $nh_cookie" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:84.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/84.0" -H "Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01" -H "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5" --compressed -H "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest" -H "Connection: keep-alive" -H "Referer: https://nhentai.net/g/$id/" -H "Pragma: no-cache" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -H "TE: Trailers" -H "Sec-GPC: 1" -H "DNT: 1" -H "Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty" -H "Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors" -H "Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin" -H "cookie: $nh_cookie" --cookie "$nh_cookie" "https://nhentai.net/api/gallery/$id"
```

But again, it just gives the `Just a moment...` Cloudflare Captcha page.

I am out of ideas, and my code is up on https://github.com/quincynyan/hentaifetch if anyone wants to PR.